# diffy can't access ldiff with vendored diff-lcs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, diff-lcs

I have a Ruby-on-Rails (3.2) application with following environment:

- Deployment: `capistrano`, standard folder structure (`my_app/current, /shared, /releases`)
- Ruby: `v2.3` installed from source at `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. Not using rvm or rbenv
- Bundler: Using [capistrano-bundler](https://github.com/capistrano/bundler), installed at `my_app` level in capistrano standard hierarchy `my_app/shared/bundler`
- App server: using [passenger-phusion with nginx](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/xenial/), startup managed with `systemctl`

Issue: I am using a gem [diffy](https://rubygems.org/gems/diffy) which uses `ldiff` executable provided by [diff-lcs](https://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs). This executable is located at `/home/my_user/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/ldiff` which is actually bundler generated stubs. Now, when I put code like this: `Diffy::Diff.new('abcd', 'abcde').to_s`, stub is executed and following error is thrown:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem diff-lcs (>= 0.a) with executable ldiff (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:263:in `bin_path'
from /home/my_user/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/ldiff:24:in `<main>'
```

Note that this works in rails console but not in server. Looking at [diffy.rb](https://github.com/samg/diffy/blob/master/lib/diffy/diff.rb#L158), I don't have control over actual command being executed by diffy (where I can put `bundle exec diffy ...`).

How to fix this? The only way seems to do away with vendored gems and install all gems at system level.

PS: I faced the same issue while using `[wkhtmltopdf][6]`, however, I `wkhtmltopdf` provides a configuration setting to use native package.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, passenger wasn't getting `PATH` properly, only location in `ENV['PATH']` was the one added by `bundler`: `/home/my_user/my_app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin`. [Phusion passenger documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html) also doesn't explicitly clarifies this behavior. Fixed this by including this directive in `nginx.conf`: `passenger_env_var PATH $PATH;`. This makes existing path to be passed to passenger processes.